# $http.put('') not reflecting changes on page reload (MEAN)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

below is code from my controller. The code properly saves the edited salary in my mongodb database, and it will reflect the change on the page. However, on page reload, the page shows the old value for salary, and does so until I log the user out and log back in. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/user').success(function(user) {
  console.log("user", user);
  $scope.user = user;
  $scope.currentUser = user.displayName;
  $scope.salary = user.salary;
});

$scope.openMoneyEdit = function() {
  $scope.salary = $scope.user.salary;
  matchId = $scope.user._id;
  console.log(matchId);
};
$scope.editMoney = function(user) {
  $http.put('/money/' + $scope.user._id, user)
  .success(function(response) {
    if (response === 'fail'){
      alert('Fail to edit ', 'Make sure year format is correct', 'error');
    } else {
      alert('Success', 'info updated.', 'success');
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Have a look at this article, particularly the section on "Dirty reads and stale reads". Sounds like you may be having the same issue. [https://aphyr.com/posts/322-call-me-maybe-mongodb-stale-reads](https://aphyr.com/posts/322-call-me-maybe-mongodb-stale-reads)

Comment: What is the code for the endpoint?